# Gridview not displaying values from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to display a database table in a DataGrid but the DataGrid isn't displaying. All I have is a textbox and under it I want the DataGrid to display the table. The textbox is displaying but the DataGrid isn't.

```
<table>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="Header">Public Holiday Date</td>
          <td>
             <asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="txtDate" rel="datepicker" ></asp:TextBox>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <asp:DataGrid runat="server" id="dataGridView1"  AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:DataGrid>    
          </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
```

The code for getting the data from the database:

```
private DataSet GetBankHolidays()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        string sql = "proc_GetAllCustomers";

        string query = "SELECT BankHol FROM bankholidays";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(sql, DataUtils.ConnectionStrings["TAT"]))
        {
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = query;
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView1.DataBind();
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

And I'm calling this method in the page load:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            GetBankHolidays();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the [DataBind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d(v=vs.110).aspx) method:-

```
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Apart from this I would suggest you to separate out the DAL & UI code.

Comment: that gives the error DataGrid with id 'dataGridView1' could not automatically generate any columns from the selected data source.

Comment: try setting `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `true`

Answer (score 1):

write `dataGridView1.DataBind();` below `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;`

Comment: that gives the error DataGrid with id 'dataGridView1' could not automatically generate any columns from the selected data source.

Comment: Set Autogeneratecolumn property of gridview to true in your aspx code

Comment: @user123456789 are you sure that Datatable contains any records. ?

Comment: @user123456789 not database i am asking does `adapter.Fill(dt);` contains records ?

Comment: try to debug and see what values come in `dt`

Comment: @user123456789 check my answer `adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` the prob is you have to specify stored procedure and not text

Comment: You have not debugged correctly. hover mouse on dt and click search like button

Comment: @ImadoddinIbnAlauddin it is coming up as blank. It is not finding the values from the database

Comment: @user123456789 does your stored procedure return records??

Answer (score 1):

Your code lacks `{dataGridView1.DataBind();}` command.

Use the `DataBind()` method to bind data from a data source to the `GridView` control.

Answer (score 0):

In your coding you are using `stored procedure` but you have 
 mentioned command type as text

```
adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

You need to bind DataSource to the DataGrid

```
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Final code

```
using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(sql, DataUtils.ConnectionStrings["TAT"]))
        {
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = query;
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView1.DataBind();
        }
```